# Finding Mean of A Column in Tuple (Python)

Tags: tuples

I have a tuple (derived from a CSV) that contains multiple columns, I am wondering how I can find the mean of one of the columns and not all the numbers, for example how would I find the mean of elements[2] (12322,2027,17148), and print that out?

```
[('Washington', 'VA', 12322, 1037, 0, 69.5, 1247.0, 26.7, 2.0),
('Alexandria', 'VA', 2027, 18453, 6870, 68.8, 1394.0, 26.2, 25.97),
('Denver', 'CO', 17148, 1472, 9365, 59.1, 1120.0, 19.0, 970.7)]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy enough to write a script that does exactly what you want just using the Python standard library.

Here's a simpler way to do it using Numpy (and possibly more efficient if you have a large array of numbers, as Numpy is designed to optimize matrix calculations).

```python
import numpy as np

# Converting list of tuples to a Numpy array.
arr = np.array(elements)

# Finding mean for the column with index 2.
print(np.mean(arr[:, 2].astype(float)))
```

The `.astype(float)` is required to typecast the strings to floats. `arr[:, 2]` means you are accessing all the rows in the column with index 2. `np.mean` is used to find the mean for the array passed to it.

You can install Numpy using `pip install numpy`. Or if you're using Anaconda, it should be preinstalled.

Refer:
[np.mean](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html)